# first paragraph of the_content as meta description

Tags: functions, the-content, excerpt

I was trying to use the_content as my meta description, however, i noticed that the texts/content is way too many so I'm thinking if it's possible to use the first paragraph only?

Here's the code I'm currently using for meta description.

```
<?php global $post;
$content = $post->post_content; if(!empty($content)) {?>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php  echo strip_tags($content); ?>" />
<?php }?>
```

Btw, The first paragraph of my the_content has a class. f-desc and here's the code I've used to add it.

```
function first_paragraph($content){
    return preg_replace('/<p([^>]+)?>/', '<p$1 class="f-desc">', $content, 1);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'first_paragraph');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `the_excerpt()` instead of the_content

Reference link for filter your excerpt : [show-first-paragraph](https://www.bybe.net/wordpress-the_excerpt-show-first-paragraph/)
Or you can also do this by callback function inside your loop using the function to modify the_content as below:

```
function get_first_paragraph(){
    global $post;

    $str = wpautop( get_the_content() );
    $str = substr( $str, 0, strpos( $str, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    $str = strip_tags($str, '<a><strong><em>');
    return $str;
}
```

Hope this helps!!